# How to prevent empty token from showing

Tags: tokens

I want to capture a value from the url and display it in a piece of content, if available.
In my node body I enter text like:

`The sid is "[current-page:query:sid]".`

If I then view that node at http://example.org/node/123?sid=foo the content shows as:

> The sid is "foo".

Excellent, all working great. Here's the problem: if I visit the page without the ?sid argument in the url (just going to /node/123), then the content displays literally as:

> The sid is "[current-page:query:sid]".

I would prefer the token to just be blank in that case. How can I get it to output

> The sid is "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for what you experiencing is the default behavior of `token_replace()` to leave tokens untouched if no replacement value was provided.

In your case, the *Token Filter* module would have to provide the option `'clear' => true` when calling `token_replace()`.

You may want to try to [apply](https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply) the patch in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2381359) to the token_filter module.